# toast output, float decimal formatting?

Tags: android, floating-point, decimal

the only way I know how to output float into 3 decimal places goes something like this...

```
DecimalFormat var = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
Toast.makeText(this,"number equals"+var.format(number),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

could i put something like the `%.3f or %3f` in Toast

i tried `"number equals"+number%3f` and `"number equals"+number%.3f`

which messes up the value

Comment: how will i print it without using "DecimalFormat"? thanks

Comment: where is the question..?.. i think you can be bit more clear about what you need here.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with the decimal formatter?

Comment: i mean how could i use the %.3f or %3f (i'm not sure which of these) in toast

Comment: but i guess i would stick for decimal format which is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I **think** the only other real way you could do this is something like this:

```
float number = (float)Math.round(oldNumber * 1000) / 1000;
string formattedNumber = Float.toString(number);
```

That will round to 3 decimal places. However I can't see why this would help you, what you've got is more than adequate.

Comment: does it mean i couldnt Toast the %.3f or %3f just like in System.out.print

Comment: no, and I don't understand why you would choose to do that over using the lovely built in functionality of decimal format. :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no notation like %.3f supported into android, so whereever, you need formatting you need to use DecimalFormat.